# Red Hat/XP: Accessing network files using file protocol

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm running Red Hat Linux 4.5 in VMWare Server (virtual machine) on Windows XP (host machine). I'm using a loopback adapter to assign an IP address of `192.168.1.100` to the VM.

How would I set up file protocol to access the VM's filesystem? Is it possible?

```
file://192.168.1.100/path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer uses the CIFS protocol for `file:` URIs, and the Linux CIFS server is [Samba](http://www.samba.org/).